# Compilation error on blocks with return type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, block

I have the following block code

```
    typedef BOOL(^FieldValidationBlock)(NSString *);
FieldValidationBlock aBlock = ^(NSString *input){
    return ([input length] == 10) ;
};
```

which throws me a compilation error thats tates the return type is int and should be BOOL.
when I add a cast it works just fine:

```
    typedef BOOL(^FieldValidationBlock)(NSString *);
FieldValidationBlock aBlock = ^(NSString *input){
    return (BOOL)([input length] == 10) ;
};
```

why this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because BOOL is an objective C type, and the logical comparison operators are standard C.  In standard C the return type of comparison operators is an int.  This is important to know sometimes, as when you negate a value that you assume to be boolean, but is in fact an int, it's not necessarily going to be what you expect.

In your example, casting to a BOOL is fine.

Comment: well, even when I try to do "[input length] == 10 ? YES :NO". which should eliminate the problem you claim, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I suspect that may be something to do with the fact that BOOLs aren't really first-class types, they're signed chars with a typedef, check objc.h.  Another way to resolve the error could be to explicitly type the block that you're assigning, and avoid the use of the type inferrer.  `FieldValidationBlock aBlock = BOOL ^(NSString *input){...}`

Comment: Sorry, meant `FieldValidationBlock aBlock = ^BOOL (NSString *input){...}`

Comment: I think it's probably a bug in the compiler.  The inferred return type is incorrect when using the ternary operator with BOOLs.  I tried it with other types (e.g. NSString *) and it's fine, just BOOLs not working as expected.  I'll file this with apple.